# Performance difference between searching table with 350 columns and searching table with 25 columns

Tags: java, performance

I am currently doing some hibernate performance test. My requirement is to search for data in a particular column of a table containing 8 million rows and 350 columns. Currently, I don't have the access to that database, however, the test database that I'm now using also contains 8millions+.

My question is, is there a significant difference in terms of scan speed when searching for a data in a table that containts 350 columns than in table containing 25 columns?

By the way, the way I check for data is :

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT COL_5 from MY_TABLE where COL_5='" + theColValuePassedFromParameter+ "'").list();
```

Where in if the returned list is empty, the boolean method will return true, else false; I would also appreciate If someone can point me to a better, performant way of searching for a non-primary key data in hibernate.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If someone can point me to a better, performant way of searching for a non-primary key data [...]

Add an index in your database on the column(s) you are filtering on - in this case `COL_5`. The resulting execution plan should be a single index seek and the performanze difference negligible (or even zero).

---

Also rather than getting the entire result set, just check if there is at least one resulting row. You can either add a `TOP 1` to your query (or whatever SQL equivalent), or add a `.setMaxResults(1)`.

Comment: Noted. I will google your suggestion further.

Answer (score 3):

You ask two quesions, firstly:

> is there a significant difference in terms of scan speed when
>   searching for a data in a table that containts 350 columns than in
>   table containing 25 columns?

If you have an index defined, then no, there should be no difference.  If you don't have an index, then there *may* be a difference.  Assuming you don't have enough RAM for your database to hold all 8 million rows in a cache, then it has to go to the disk to fetch each row, in which case there will be some IO overhead.  The more data that has to be fetched from disk, the more overhead this will be.  Obviously there's likely to be some correlation between the number of columns and the total size of the row's data.

Secondly:

> I would also appreciate If someone can point me to a better,
>   performant way of searching for a non-primary key data in hibernate.

As [lc.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44853/lc) mentioned in his answer, using an index and, if all you are really interested in is the existence of any row that matches the criteria, either 'TOP 1', or select the number rows directly in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(COL_5) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COL_5=?
```

Comment: I modified my query like you suggested but it seems more slower than hibernate's `criteria.list` with `setMaxResults`.

Comment: @onepotato, having thought about it, that does make sense.  Using a row limit of 1, the DB query processor can stop after it finds a single row, whereas using `COUNT`, every single row still needs to be processed.

Answer (score 3):

In response to your question about the performance difference in querying a table with 300 vs 25 columns, it really depends on the specs of your database server. In general, the greater the number of columns the more likely is that the rowsize exceeds the blocksize and rows are stored in a chained way.

There are two types of row chaining: [Intra-Block and Inter-Block](http://dbcrusade.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/intra-block-versus-inter-block-row.html), the latter generating more performance issue than the former.

This is an interesting page about the performance impact of [Intra-Block chaining](http://viveklsharma.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/intra-block-chaining-impact-on-logical-reads/#comments).

As for your query, note that building an index on col_5 is only worth it if this column has a high cardinality (holds a great number of different values), otherwise the optimiser will disregard the index and opt for a table scan regardless.

Comment: We use Oracle. I will also research on that.

Comment: [Oracle 11g Row Chaining and Migrating](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/logical.htm#i15914)

Comment: Can you give me a good article in Oracle 10g?

Comment: The documentation on [this point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/logical.htm#i15914) has not changed between 10g and 11g.